# Python/Matplotlib: saving figures as .png but axis text as .pdf or .eps

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, png

I am doing some Matplotlib figures with a lot of data. When saving these as `.pdf`-files the figures become very large and take a long time to render; however the I much prefer the `.pdf`-format for the axes text. My figure-saving workflow is something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)

fig.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

or

```
fig.savefig('plot.png', dpi=600)
```

**Question:** Is there a way to save a figure with the plot-part as a picture (`.png`) and the text (axis-labels etc.) as vector graphics (`.pdf`)?

Cheers!